# How to use the same parameter more than once in a query

Tags: sql, sql-server-mobile

I want to run a query similar to this one on a SqlCE database:

```
SELECT t.Field1, t.Field2
FROM MyTable t
WHERE t.Field1 = @Param
UNION ALL
SELECT t2.Field1, t2.Field2
FROM MyOtherTable t2
WHERE t2.Field1 = @Param
```

However, running this results in the error message:

> Duplicated parameter names are not
>   allowed. [  Parameter name = @Param ]

A workaround is of course to define `@Param1` and `@Param2` and assign them the same value, but this feels a bit dirty to me. Is there a cleaner workaround for this problem?

Comment: Is this query executed by sp_executesql?

Comment: I'm not familiar with sp_executesql, I create a `SqlCeCommand` object which I execute using the `ExecuteReader` method.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT t.Field1, t.Field2
FROM MyTable t
UNION ALL
SELECT t2.Field1, t2.Field2
FROM MyOtherTable t2
) sub
WHERE sub.Field1 = @Param
```

Comment: Thinking in the same way - create view or table-function (with 1 param) from UNION and use it as simple query.

Answer (score 0):

Add the parameter only once to the parameter collection. You can use it how may times you like in the query.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used SQL CE, but maybe this will work:

```
DECLARE @P int

SET @P = @Param

SELECT t.Field1, t.Field2
FROM MyTable t
WHERE t.Field1 = @P
UNION ALL
SELECT t2.Field1, t2.Field2
FROM MyOtherTable t2
WHERE t2.Field1 = @P
```